# How to display multiple images in single image tag, I have an array of images in my ts file, I need to display in html

Tags: html, image

Need to display multiple images in html, I have selected multiple images from camera roll, all those images have to displayed in html part

Comment: Share the code you have tried first.

Comment: I have used image picker getPictures method
In ts file:
   this.imagePicker.getPictures(cameraOptions).then((results) => {
      // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-for-of
      for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        this.imageSrc = results[i];
        console.log('image', this.imageSrc);
      }
    }, (err) => { });
  }
In html file:
   <img src={{imageSrc}} />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you have to put array of images in a single image tag ?

Just insert them into html using JS innerHTML.

```
//considering you have images in a variable for js...
for(var i=0;i<imageArray.length;i++){
document.getElementById("yourParentDiv").innerHTML+=<img src="imageArray[i]"></img>

}
```

Or if you could explain the reason for not using this approach, would like to help furthermore.